# Home.php isn't working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue with home.php on a WordPress theme I'm developing.

I'm trying to make a page that displays the latest posts. I've ascertained that this is called 'home.php.'

I'm following a tutorial that includes a template for home.php. The problem is, the home.php isn't being read. Instead, it seems that the browser is showing index.php in place of home.php. I know it's not posting anything from home.php because because if I delete all the code from the home.php and save it as a blank document, it has zero effect on what the browser displays.

Here's the PHP/HTML I'm using:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">

  <h1>News</h1>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p><em><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y'); ?></em></p>
<hr>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p><?php _e('Sorry, there are no posts.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>

<div class="span4">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?> 
</div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: This may help explain some of the template order: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#home-page-display

Comment: Do you have a template file named `front-page.php` too? What is your "Front page displays" setting set to?

Comment: In the WordPress admin interface, what is your setting under "Settings->Reading->Front page displays"? This in combination with the presence or absence of front-page.php as mentioned will determine whether `home.php` is shown at your site's root URL. (It is the page at the site's root URL you're looking at, yes?)

Comment: Yeah after reading into this a little more it turns out that front-page.php is what's being displayed, not index.php

Comment: what happens if you add `<?php $args = array('paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ), ); query_posts($args); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Change your opening line `<?php get_header(); ?>` to the following

```
<?php
    /* Template Name: Homepage */
    get_header();
?>
```

Then go and create a page inside of the WordPress admin area and assign that page to use the template named "Homepage" by changing the dropdown in this screenshot: http://smb-infogroup-dpr.d.pr/Jw4P/2cXQVFLL

Then you'll need to go to Settings > Reading and set the two options in this screenshot: http://smb-infogroup-dpr.d.pr/Svk0/58SLZIEq. The second option will be the name of the page you created and assigned the template to.

index.php is the default template file used unless you assign a static page to the homepage.